# How to perform division of BigIntegers with bigger denominator than numerator and exponentiating it to 1/x where x is also biginteger

Tags: biginteger, division, bigdecimal, exponentiation

I am trying to solve the equation A = ( ( Z/(U.S^v) ) ^ 1/e  ) mod n, and all the variables are bigintegers. The denominator is much bigger than the numberator, the numerator being about 50 digits and denominator is of above 250 digits. the answer i get is 0 for the division.

i tried bigdecimal as well, that also gives me same problem.

Comment: If that "mod n" means what it looks like it means, then that division isn't even a division at all but a multiplication by the multiplicative inverse modulo n, and a similar story for the "e-th root". Is that the case? Or is it really just intended as bignum math and hoping that it will be an integral result?

Comment: are you saying i should try A = ( ( Z * (U^ -1) * (S^ -v) ) ^ (e^-1) ) mod n ??i tried this one, it does give me an answer but i was not sure whether i am doing it right.

Comment: Looks about right, but I can't check your results for you. Don't you have any test cases?